# Cartesian product of schemes

Tags: algebraic-geometry, category-theory, schemes

Given schemes $X,Y$, then what's the relation between $X\times_{\text{Spec}\mathbb{Z}}Y$ and the Cartesian product $X\times Y$? Can we identify them?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I guess by the "Cartesian product" you mean the product as sets.

There is the canonical map (of schemes) from $X\times_{\operatorname{Spec}{\mathbb Z}}Y$ to $X$, which can be viewed as a map of the underlying sets. Same for the map from $X\times_{\operatorname{Spec}{\mathbb Z}}Y$ to $Y$.

These two maps then gives a map of sets $f:X\times_{\operatorname{Spec}{\mathbb Z}}Y\rightarrow X\times Y$.

However, the map $f$ is in general neither injective nor surjective.

This is easily seen from the following examples:

- $X = \operatorname{Spec}\mathbb Z[x]$, $Y = \operatorname{Spec}\mathbb Z[y]$, $X\times_{\operatorname{Spec}{\mathbb Z}}Y = \operatorname{Spec}\mathbb Z[x, y]$.

  The map $f$ is then not injective: the image of the prime ideal $(x + y)$ is the same as the image of the prime ideal $(0)$.
- $X = \operatorname{Spec}\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z$, $Y = \operatorname{Spec}\mathbb Z/3\mathbb Z$, $X\times_{\operatorname{Spec}{\mathbb Z}}Y = \operatorname{Spec}0$.

  The map $f$ is then obviously not surjective, since $X\times_{\operatorname{Spec}{\mathbb Z}}Y$ is empty as a set.

Comment: $k[x]\otimes_kk[y]=k[x,y]$ but here is $k[x]\otimes_Zk[y]$

Comment: @6666 Oh yes... I'll change it to $\mathbb Z[x]$.

Comment: And I think Spec$0$ is not empty it just has one element as the $X\times Y$

Comment: And I think the tensor $Z[x]\otimes_ZZ[Y]\cong Z[x,y]$ is an iso as modules not as algebras, so when we don't have the equality of spec

Comment: No, $\operatorname{Spec}0$ is considered empty https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero_ring

Comment: And $\mathbb Z[x] \otimes _{\mathbb Z}\mathbb Z[y] \simeq \mathbb Z[x, y]$ is an isomorphism of algebras. Anyway you already accepted the other answer, meaning that I misunderstood your question.

Comment: I accept yours now, I think you mean the product depends on which category we think right? Like if we consider the category of schemes, then the product is the fiber product over Spec Z

Comment: You didn't misunderstand me and your examples are very helpful

Comment: I think spec0 is empty set in the category of schemes by your link, but when we consider the category of Set, it's not empty.

Comment: The underlying set of $\operatorname{Spec}0$ is the empty set, since it doesn't have any prime ideal. By definition, an ideal $I$ of a ring $R$ is prime iff the quotient ring $A/I$ is integral. But the zero ring is by convention not integral.

Answer (score 2):

Subject to all of these things existing, the product is exactly the fiber product over the final object. This may be proven by noting that both constructions satisfy the same universal property, so they are canonically isomorphic.

Compare the universal properties defining both constructions. We take as our setup $X,Y$ two objects with $Z$ the final object and $c_X:X\to Z,c_y:Y\to Z$ the canonical morphisms to the final object.

- Product: the product is the unique object $X\times Y$ equipped with morphisms $p_X:X\times Y\to X$ and $p_Y:X\times Y\to Y$ so that for any other object $Q$ with maps $f_X:Q\to X$ and $f_Y:Q\to Y$, there exists a unique morphism $f:Q\to X\times Y$.
- Fiber product over $Z$: the fiber product is the unique object $X\times_Z Y$ equipped with morphisms $p_X':X\times_Z Y \to X$ and $p_Y':X\times_Z Y \to Y$ so that for any other object $R$ with maps $g_X:R\to X$ and $g_Y: R\to Y$ so that $c_X\circ g_X = c_Y\circ g_Y$, there exists a unique morphism $g:R\to X\times_Z Y$.

We note that the condition $c_X\circ g_X=c_Y\circ g_Y$ is vacuously true since there is only one morphism $R\to Z$ by the definition of $Z$ being a final object. So we see that the universal property satisfied by the fiber product over the final object is the same universal property as that satisfied by the product. As the object satisfying a universal property must be unique up to unique isomorphism, we see that $X\times Y \cong X\times_Z Y$ in any category possessing both products, fiber products, and a final object. In particular, this is true in both sets and schemes.

Comment: I think this is true in the category of schemes but not true in the category of sets

Comment: No, this is true in every category with all of these things (product, fiber product, and final object).  I've expanded my answer. If you're interested in the underlying sets of these constructions, then you should say so in your question. Currently formulated, it reads to me like you are asking about the product and fiber product inside the category of schemes. This answer doesn't apply if you're asking about the underlying set of the fiber product and the product as sets, because the fiber product in schemes does not give the scheme who's underlying space is the fiber product of those spaces.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. Sorry for the confusion, I was confused because I didn’t realize the products in different categories are different.